# valuechange events in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm wondering how to attach an event listener to a variable... I know that sounds super weird so here's what I'm working with.

```
B.viewController = function() {
  var view = 'large';

  var update = function() {
    if($(window).width() >= 481) {
      var new-view = 'large';
      return view == new-view
    } else {
      var new-view = 'mobile';
      return view == new-view;
    }
  }

  update();

  $(window).resize(function() {
    update();
  });
};
```

now i'd like to expand this so that I can attach it as an event listener so for example I could use this to do something like coolImage.bind('B.viewController', callback) So that if the view changes the callback is called without having to attach a resize listener to the window...

Comment: That sounds super weird... =)

Comment: You cannot use dashes in variable names!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to custom events to do the job.

Here is an example:

```
var Publisher = {}, Subscriber = {}, EVENT_NAME = 'publisher.updated',
    PubSub = $({});

Publisher.update = function() {
    PubSub.trigger(EVENT_NAME);
};

Subscriber.onUpdate = function() {
    alert('Received update!');
};

PubSub.bind(EVENT_NAME, Subscriber.onUpdate);
Publisher.update();
```

Publisher triggers an event when update is called, and Subscriber listens to the event when the event is triggered.

Applying this to your case, when `B.viewController` is updated, you can call `PubSub.trigger('view.updated')` to trigger an update event. And then, have `coolImage` listen to the event by `PubSub.bind('view.updated', coolImage.onViewUpdated)`.

Credit/Reference

- JSFilddle of the PubSub code: http://jsfiddle.net/cwZZE/17/
- PubSub idea is borrowed from Ben Alman's Tiny Pub/Sub library: https://gist.github.com/799721/c119783954e1b10551c4afef53b2c04fefcb7465

Comment: There is no such thing as a 'Javascript event mechanism'. In your code you are using jQuery's `trigger` and `bind` functions with some custom messages.

Answer (score 0):

For the events on HTML elements: I would write a big Listener class. It would have a function to bind itself to an element. This function would bind the Listener's internal methods as the callback functions of all the element's events, like `onload`, `onclick` etc. Then you would instantiate the Listener for different kinds of listeners, assigning actual functions to the Listener's internal methods. Another option is to bind all those events to a single callback function, which would get a single parameter - the event description. If I recall correctly, IE doesn't always send that parameter - if that is true, you should look to `window.event`. In this function you will process all the events done. And if you still want to discern which event has occured, you may do so by the type of that object holding the event details.

For the events of variables: I have not encountered something like this. It is not present in most programming languages and I don't think it is present in javascript. I would suggest using the good old OOP practice - getters and setter. So you will write `a.set(x)` instead of `a = x` and `a.getX()` instead of `a.x` and in these methods, you can handle the changes if needed.